# wineboot error: failed to start RpcSs service

Tags: wine

I'm trying to get office2021 running on wine (maybe a doomed project, i know) and I'm following these directions:
https://ruados.github.io/articles/2021-05/office365-wine

I started by thoroughly uninstalling any previous versions of wine and playonlinux from my computer, and every step of the process has gone well so far.

However, when I try `wineboot -i` I get the following set of error messages:

```
astrid@boat3:~$ wineboot -i
002c:fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" (6.0.0.0)
0048:fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" (6.0.0.0)
0050:fixme:actctx:parse_depend_manifests Could not find dependent assembly L"Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls" (6.0.0.0)
MESA-INTEL: warning: MESA-INTEL: warning: Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0
Performance support disabled, consider sysctl dev.i915.perf_stream_paranoid=0


0048:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hr 0x80004002
0048:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, hr 0x80004002
0048:err:ole:apartment_get_local_server_stream Failed: 0x80004002
0048:err:ole:start_rpcss Failed to open RpcSs service
0050:err:ole:StdMarshalImpl_MarshalInterface Failed to create ifstub, hr 0x80004002
0050:err:ole:CoMarshalInterface Failed to marshal the interface {6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa}, hr 0x80004002
0050:err:ole:apartment_get_local_server_stream Failed: 0x80004002
0050:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x4b2450, 0): stub
0050:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (00010020, 004B2450): stub
002c:fixme:imm:ImeSetActiveContext (0x482138, 1): stub
002c:fixme:imm:ImmReleaseContext (0001004E, 00482138): stub
0090:fixme:file:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
0090:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
0090:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0090:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0090:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0090:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0098:fixme:file:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
0098:fixme:ntdll:NtQuerySystemInformation info_class SYSTEM_PERFORMANCE_INFORMATION
0098:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0098:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0098:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0098:err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
0098:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 5)
0098:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 5)
0090:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 1)
0090:fixme:msi:internal_ui_handler internal UI not implemented for message 0x0b000000 (UI level = 1)
wine: configuration in L"/home/astrid/.msoffice" has been updated.

astrid@boat3:~$ 0050:err:ole:start_rpcss Failed to start RpcSs service
0118:err:rpc:I_RpcReceive we got fault packet with status 0x1c010003
012c:err:rpc:RpcServerAssoc_FindContextHandle no context handle found for uuid {4bbf989a-b938-4006-ad52-931e1561014c}, guard 00000000
0118:err:rpc:I_RpcReceive we got fault packet with status 0x1c00001a
010c:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"MountMgr" failed to start: 1053
010c:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"wineusb" failed to start: 1115
010c:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"winebus" failed to start: 1115
010c:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"PlugPlay" failed to start: 1115
010c:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"Eventlog" failed to start: 1115
010c:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"nsiproxy" failed to start: 1115
010c:fixme:service:scmdatabase_autostart_services Auto-start service L"NDIS" failed to start: 1115
```

I have fully uninstalled and reinstalled wine three times, each with the same result. Any leads?

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a thinkpad. Let me know what further information is needed!